# Jsp Project not running

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

I have created a web project  which includes .jsp and Java beans pages. When I run this project with eclipse, using tomcat it works perfectly fine, I deployed the project successfully, the program runs and I receive a web page in the browser.

But when I try to deploy war file in webapps folder of tomcat6 and run on browser it gives error –
This is the error I see on the page:

```
HTTP status 404. Description: the requested resource is not available.
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: When do you get the error? When you access the first page itself, or sometime later (when you try to access an image for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have file index.html/index.jsp in your war if it is not there then you have to either need to change the name of file that is opened in context "/" or you have to make changes in  list.

Answer (score 0):

To create WAR file using eclipse, follow the option File -> export -> Web > War File and finally select project and destination folder. To deploy war file in Tomcat, place the war file in Tomcat Installation Directory > webapps directory and start the Tomcat.
Hope this is useful for you !!